# Retrieve POST param with Swagger2 & Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am developing a web service with Symfony3 and I am using [Swagger-PHP 2.0.6](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) for documenting it.

To make it simple, here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Post(path="/user",
 *   tags={"user"},
 *   summary="Registers a new user",
 *   operationId="registerUserAction",
 *   produces={"application/json"},
 *   @SWG\Parameter(
 *     in="body",
 *     name="user",
 *     description="User to register",
 *     required=true,
 *     @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/UserInput")
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="User registered"
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(
 *     response=400,
 *     description="Invalid input"
 *   )
 * )
 * @var UserInput $user
 * @return JsonResponse
 **/
public function registerUserAction(UserInput $user)
{
    // Do stuff with the user model

    return new JsonResponse();
}
```

My route is define as so:

```
postUser:
    path: /user
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:User:registerUser }
    methods: [POST]
```

Now here is the error that I have from Symfony:

> Controller "MyBundle\Controller\UserController::registerUserAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$user" argument (because
>   there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one). (500 Internal Server Error)

Workaround would be to pass the Request object instead to the controller and then get the values directly from $request->request but this is not what I am trying to achieve here.

So the question is, is there any way to achieve this? I remember I used to do it before on a Symfony2 application with Swagger 1.x

PS: I am also using Swagger-UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for those interested, I managed to make it work using a custom [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) :)